# PHP json_decode returns null with Symfony

Tags: php, json, rest, api, symfony

I'm working on REST APIs with Symfony but my json_decode function returns null with my array. I've seen that he can be a probleme with encoding but i'm not sure.
Here's my json :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Titre",
    "content": "Contenu",
    "vendeur": null
}
```

Here's my functions to serialize and decode json :

```
/**
 * @Route("/api_articles_list", name="api_articles_list")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */

public function showActionListSerialize()

{

    $articles =   $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->findAll();

   // return new JsonResponse(array('articles' => $articles));

    $data =  $this->get('serializer')->serialize($articles, 'json');

    $response = new Response($data);

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');


    return $response;



}

/**
 * @Route("/api_articles_list/articles_list", name="articles_list")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function showActionList()

{

    $articles = json_decode(utf8_encode($this->showActionListSerialize()), true);

    var_dump($articles);
    return $this->render('listeArticles.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));

}
```

Comment: what does $articles return in showActionListSerialize ?  I think you'll need to write it like this $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->findAll()

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, you don't decode arrays, you might want to clarify that in your question. That said, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to encode an array, put the encode function after serializing the list:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api_articles_list", name="api_articles_list")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */

public function showActionListSerialize()

{

    $articles =   $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Article')->findAll();

   // return new JsonResponse(array('articles' => $articles));

    $data =  $this->get('serializer')->serialize($articles, 'json');

    $response = new Response(utf8_encode($data));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');


    return $response;



}

/**
 * @Route("/api_articles_list/articles_list", name="articles_list")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function showActionList()

{

    $articles = json_decode($this->showActionListSerialize(), true);

    var_dump($articles);
    return $this->render('listeArticles.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));

}
```

Comment: Would you explain  me why encoding the data after serializing the list? The findAll function return an array of object. In fact the symfony Serializer does 2 things when you call the serialize method. First, it performs a normalization to convert the data into a well formed array. It is a recursive action so the normalizer check the type of the data and chose the corresponding normalizer. As it is an array of Article objects, it will use ObjectNormalizer each time it finds an Article. Then after the normalization step is done, the Symfony serializer performs a json_encode.

Comment: I was talking about the "utf8_encode" function, this function acceptes only parameter of type "string", in your code, you return an object of type "Reponse" so the function "utf8_encode" will be applied to the object "response" not the serialized json.

Comment: Oh alright but actually that's not the reason why $articles variable is null

Answer (score 0):

First of all Welcome to StackOverflow,

Your second controller should look like this in order to achieve your goal:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api_articles_list/articles_list", name="articles_list")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function showActionList()
{
    $articles = json_decode(utf8_encode($this->showActionListSerialize()->getContent()), true);

    var_dump($articles);

    return $this->render('listeArticles.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));

}
```

First using utf8_encode is not mandatory. Then your method **showActionListSerialize** returns a HttpFoundation **Response** object.

When you instanciated the response with the serialized data like this:

```
$response = new Response($data);
```

in fact it is the same as doing:

```
$response->setContent($data);
```

So to access the JSON data you need the **getContent** method.

The actual output of

```
var_dump(utf8_encode($this->showActionListSerialize());
```

is :

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type:
>   application/json Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 13:25:22 GMT
>   [{"content":"Lorem
>   ipsum","vendeur":"test_vendeur","id":1,"title":"title_test"}]"

and the output of

```
var_dump(utf8_encode($this->showActionListSerialize()->getContent());
```

is

> [{"content":"Lorem
>   ipsum","vendeur":"test_vendeur","id":1,"title":"title_test"}]

This solution should work for you. And your twig template should looks like:

```
{% block body %}
    {% for article in articles %}
        <br>
        id: {{ article.id }} <br>
        title: {{ article.title }}<br>
        content: {{ article.content }}<br>
        vendeur: {{ article.vendeur }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, don't forget to mark this answer as beeing the solution of your issue if it really solved it.